# Why does PC Principal crosses his arms in this way?

Tags: character, south-park

Why does PC principal crosses his arms with his thumbs up? This has been bothering me ever since his character was included in South Park series. Is there any significance or reason to this at all? Or this is just part of one of his quirks?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some people cross their arms like that. Supposedly it shows a superior attitude.

https://www.indiabix.com/body-language/arm-barriers-gestures/

Comment: Also crossing your arms like that lets you exaggerate the size of you biceps by using your knuckles to push them up/out.